# ASP.Net MVC3 and jQuery UI Tabs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui-tabs

I have created a HTML layout below with jQuery UI tabs
All the tab information are related to Employee

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Deparment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Salary Info</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Some fiels here</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
                <p>Some fiels here</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
                <p>Some fiels here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

All i need is i want to keep this in MVC page.

Can i have all tabs in one View or i can use @Html.Partial? or PartialViewResult? for each tab.

Some time the user may update only Department information. Here i should save only that tab information.

**I want all these tabs loaded at first time and not in on demand using ajax.**

**Can anyone suggest how can i organize my need in MVC?**

***Note:*** Also another thing is i want to use the same for Add and Edit employee. In case of Add Employee i should able to view only Basic Detail as enabled and other tabs in disabled mode. Once the user save basic detail other tab should get enabled.

Answer (score 1):

1. View fragmentation:
   You can do either single view, or split it on multiple partials. It doesn't really matter till  they render necessary html.
2. To save information from each tab separately, wrap each tab content in `<form />`, so you'll have multiple forms instead of one.
3. To show next tab on submit, solution will depend on submit process. If you have synchronous  Post(Get) then you'll have to pass pass tab parameter with `Response` and depend on response open next tab on DOM ready (use jQuery for that). Otherwise, if you submit tabs with ajax, you may switch tab in your handler.

Comment: Do i use Partial or RenderPartial helper method in main view? How about the return type for each partial view in controller is it ActionResult or PartialViewResult?

Comment: Html.Partial and Html.RenderPartial will give same result. Use Html.Partial, it has clearer syntax. If your view will be used only as partial, use PartialViewResult.

Comment: Sure. I use Partial. When i create my view i select check box Create Partial View and return a PartialViewResult from controller. This view never be used as a single page, they always go as a sub section of a page. Is it ok?